# slideToggle; new web developer here

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide, slidetoggle

New web developer here so please bear with me...

I'm creating an FAQ page on our site with 10-15 questions that I would like to display the answer to after clicking on the question.

Example:

Q.  What is your name?

(after clicking the question, the answer will slide down displaying the text)

Adam

I would also like for you to be able to click the question again to hide the answer once the viewer has read it.

Thank you for your time!

HTML:

```
<p>Q. WHO IS REQUIRED TO PARTICIPATE? </p> 
<p>Everyone must participate. </p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("p").click(function() { 
        $("p").slideToggle(200); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Any code that you have written??

Comment: <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <body>
 <p>Q.  WHO IS REQUIRED TO PARTICIPATE?
 </p>
 <p>Everyone must participate.
 </p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("p").click(function() {
  $("p").slideToggle(200);
 });
});
</script>

Comment: Welcome to the community! Try creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the code you've written so far, it helps us to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is better if you encase the question and corresponding answer inside a Separate div..

**HTML**

```
    <div>
        <p class="question">Q. WHO IS REQUIRED TO PARTICIPATE?</p> 
        <p class="answer">Everyone must participate. </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="question">Q. MINIMUM AGE OF THE PARTICIPANT ?</p> 
        <p class="answer">26. </p>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.question').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle(200);
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/dBG6E/)**
​

Answer (score 0):

#### Try using this code.

Even though you are a beginner, using semantic tags like, `UL` and `LI` is semantic and good. Giving `H3` and `P` for the questions and answers are useful because, it works even when the CSS is not present.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="faq">
    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">Question 1</a></h3>
        <p>Answer</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3><a href="#">Question 2</a></h3>
        <p>Answer</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.faq > li > h3 > a').click(function(){
    $(this.parentNode).next().slideToggle(200);
    return false;
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhvZx/

Comment: Compare to the other answer,

Comment: @ArjunRaj Please see my explanation. Depends on people. Even a basic web developer knows which is best. Just don't think of looking for answers, which serves the immediate purpose. Look for the quality and think about the scalable aspects like SEO, semantics, and other stuffs. :)

Comment: he needed to do it in 'p'. not using any other html elements.

Comment: He didn't mention it explicitly.

Comment: Another question: How do I make it so the answer is not already shown? I'd like you to click the question then the answer will show

Comment: @AdamPhillips I gave that in the fiddle. Use `$('.faq > li > p').hide();`. Did you check the fiddle?